# Close swing application using Jubula client api in java

Tags: java, jubula

I am using Jubula 8.7.1. I am writing my test in Java using client api. The test run s well but at the end application does not close. I tried
aut.disconnect();
But this disconnects from AUT and does not close the application. 
I am looking for something like driver.close() in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine to close a application: 

    `AUTIdentifier autId= agent.startAUT(someConfiguration);
    agent.stopAUT(autId);`

agent is the AutAgent you have set up, and someConfiguration is the configuration you are using to start the AUT.

Comment: Thanks Marvin for your response. Jubula still does not close my swing application hence i cannot have a sequential test execution. The code is tried this time is: aut.disconnect();
autagent.stopAUT(autidentifier);
autagent.disconnect();

Also tried by putting some static wait but only to fail:(
Please let me know if there is any suggestion.

Comment: Hi Rupayan. Could you share how you launch swing project with jubula. I'm new in automation and need to launch .msi file. When I add its path in AUT it gives error that java binary not found. I have java8 installed on my windows